# Running H2 recovery script fails with [42000-200]

Tags: java, database, h2

I have my H2 database corrupted (for unknown reason) having `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Chunk 1936 not found [1.4.200/9]`.
Now I try to recover data. I made the following steps:

1. `java -cp h2*.jar org.h2.tools.Recover`
2. `java -cp h2*.jar org.h2.tools.RunScript -url “jdbc:h2:file:~/tmp/recovery” -user user -password password -script file_generated_by_previous_step.mv.txt -showResults`

Second step starts and generates a lot of output (about processed roots and chunks), but then fails with error:

```
 [42000-200]
        at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:453)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:429)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:205)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:181)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.getSyntaxError(DbException.java:229)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.getSyntaxError(Parser.java:1051)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:1013)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:843)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:819)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:738)
        at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:657)
        at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:595)
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1235)
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeInternal(JdbcStatement.java:212)
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.execute(JdbcStatement.java:201)
        at org.h2.tools.RunScript.process(RunScript.java:224)
        at org.h2.tools.RunScript.process(RunScript.java:192)
        at org.h2.tools.RunScript.process(RunScript.java:328)
        at org.h2.tools.RunScript.runTool(RunScript.java:143)
        at org.h2.tools.RunScript.main(RunScript.java:70)
```

As a result generated `recovery.mv.db` is just an empty database with no data.

Please, help to extract any data from corrupted H2 database. I swear, I will never use this database again.

Answer (score 0):

The error you posted might due to a bug in the SHUTDOWN DEFRAG procedure.

I had the same issue and solved it by opening the DB using the latest version of H2, which at the time of writing is 2.1.212.

For reference, [the H2 changelog](http://h2database.com/html/changelog.html) and the (suspected) issue link [Possibility of corruption after SHUTDOWN DEFRAG](https://github.com/h2database/h2database/issues/3471).